# data.table shifting variable with missing ID

Tags: r, data.table

My problem is I have data of stocks with monthly variable TICKER name, RETURN and date-month. I want to calculate Forward 1-month return so I would use shift() function with leads in data.table.

Here is my data for example, this data.table is called A.

```
date.mth    TICKER    RETURN
  201501       ABC         1
  201501       DEF         2
  201501       GHI         3
  201502       ABC         4
  201502       DEF         5
  201502       JKL         6
```

As you can see:
TICKER "GHI" is not trading in 201502.
TICKER "JKL" is not trading in 201501. 
Both will have no return in LEAD.RETURN

If I use the code:

```
A[, LEAD.RETURN := shift(RETURN, 1L, fill=NA, type="lead"), by=.(date.mth,TICKER)]
```

Then data.table does not know what to do with the missing firm so it will return something like:

```
date.mth    TICKER    RETURN    LEAD1.RETURN
  201501       ABC         1             NA
  201501       DEF         2             NA
  201501       GHI         3             NA
  201502       ABC         4             NA
  201502       DEF         5             NA
  201502       JKL         6             NA
```

The result I want is if that firm not existed then in LEAD1.RETURN, I will force it to NA:

```
 date.mth    TICKER    RETURN    LEAD1.RETURN
  201501       ABC         1              4
  201501       DEF         2              5
  201501       GHI         3             NA
  201502       ABC         4             NA
  201502       DEF         5             NA
  201502       JKL         6             NA
```

I know in STATA, when you let the program know the series with TICKER and RETURN then define the lead series as F1.RETURN, it will lead 1 period automatically. F2.RETURN will lead 2 periods automatically.

Is there any way to do it in data.table or should I write a for loop on it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think removing `date.mth` from groupby should give the desired result.

```
A[, LEAD.RETURN := shift(RETURN, 1L, fill=NA, type="lead"), by=.(TICKER)]
print(A)

     date.mth TICKER RETURN LEAD.RETURN
1:   201501    ABC      1           4
2:   201501    DEF      2           5
3:   201501    GHI      3          NA
4:   201502    ABC      4          NA
5:   201502    DEF      5          NA
6:   201502    JKL      6          NA
```

Comment: But then my whole sample is from 201501 to 201712. This will work if it is only two periods I would guess? Perhaps I should state clearly

Comment: Not sure if I understand you but it work for all periods as long as the data is sorted by date.mth. Since we are shifting one value after groupby, the next ABC return gets shifted one row above.

Comment: Yes it works! I get the desired result. I think when i make groupby I want to make sure it leads correctly so i add date.mth.